# disable the ui-widget-overlay on a dialog modal

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I've been stuck for a long time, I need to disable or disappear the overlay (ui-widget-overlay) of the modal dialog from jquery, the first problem was that the overlay comes on front of my dialog and I've tried everything to put it behind and nothing works, tried all the z-index there out there in answers and nothing happened, so I'm tired of it and I just want to remove it.

this is the code:

```
<script>


    UINestable.init();

    $(function() {
        $( "#dragQueen" ).dialog({
            closeOnEscape: true,
            modal: false,

            open: function () {
                $(".ui-widget-overlay").remove();
                $('.modal-dialog').addClass("fixed");
                $('.ui-dialog-title').css("display","none");
                $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').css("display","none");

            },
        });
    });




</script>

<style>

    .fixed {
        position: absolute !important;
        padding: 0px !important;
        width: 300% !important;
        height: auto !important;
        margin-left: 25% !important;
        margin-right: 25% !important;
        z-index:9999 !important;
    }

</style>
```

Pleas could someone help me:

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> 
function openPopup() {

        $("#sth").dialog("open");

    }

 $(document).ready(function () {

        var dialog;
        dialog = $("#sth").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 500,
            height: 800,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,

            open: function () {
                $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('position', 'fixed');
                $('.ui-dialog').css('z-index', 103);
                $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('z-index', 102);
            },

            close: function () {
                $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('position', 'absolute');
            }
        });
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();//hide title bar.


    });
</script>

html:
<td>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("link text", "action Name", "myController", null,
                     new AjaxOptions
                     {
                         HttpMethod = "GET",
                         InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                         UpdateTargetId = "sth",
                         OnSuccess = "openPopup",

                     },
                       null
                     )
        </td>
```

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55809113/edit) some explanation to your answer